# ggplot2: Create an independent copy from an ggplot-Object

Tags: r, oop, ggplot2

I'm not sure how to put this in OO-Speech. But when you are creating a ggplot it will be dependent from the source data.frame. So how can you save a ggplot without that dependency?

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))  
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()  
g  

dat <- NULL  
g
```

The second $g$ won't produce a plot hence dat is $NULL$. How can I save $g$ so that dat can be changed?

I know it is not good practice but I got some very long code on which I don't want to fiddle about.

Comment: Could you not just save and then load the workspace?

Comment: Actually, the "second g" does produce a plot, regardless of whether dat is set to NULL. And g does contain the data: try typing g$data.

Comment: WE NEED VERSION NUMBERS, PEOPLE!!! packageDescription("ggplot2")$Version = 0.9.1 and g has a copy of the data in the $data element. I can't believe this would change. To keep a reference to data so that the plot changes if data changes would be a very strange thing to do...

Comment: @James look at the master branch for ggplot2 [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/plot.r)  note that the data frame method for `ggplot` creates a "data" element.  Turning on blaming, looks like that bit of code was written by hadley and has been there since 2007-11-06.  Further that file was most recently edited today, and the data element was left, so I think it is safe to say it has been there, is there now, and probably will be there at least in the next revision.

Comment: @Joshua Yes, you are right. For some reason I thought the ggplot objects are smaller now and that was the cause. I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I think that @Joshua's answer is too complicated (if I'm understanding what you want to do).

I don't think it makes any sense to change the data frame stored in the plot object, since **ggplot2** has a special infix operator that is specifically designed to apply a new data frame to a given plot object: `%+%`.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))  
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()  
g
```

[image]

```
#Change the data frame
dat$y <- rexp(10)
#Replot g using the altered data frame
g %+% dat
```

[image]

This works, of course, with not just altered versions of the original data frame, but an entirely new data frame, provided it has all the required variables in it (and they are named the same).

Comment: Furthermore you could create a dummy empty data.frame with the same structure as your original data (say, `dat[FALSE,]`) and assign that data to the plot, save the result, and then when you want to use other data, assign that new data in; the saved plot will be data-less, but not data-structure-less.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are several options, I show in order of my preference.

```
## setup
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(10) # make reproducible
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10))
```

My favorite option is to create a simple function wrapper to your code.  Then whenever you need to change the data, just pass new data to your function, and it will give it to `ggplot` and create the new graph.  This is flexible and fairly robust to problems.  It is also extensible, in that if later you decide you would also like to be able to change the title, you can just add a title argument to your function too.

```
## my favorite option
myplot <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
}

## use it
myplot(data = dat)
```

[image: first plot]

```
## change it
dat <- data.frame(x = 11:20, y = runif(10))
myplot(data = dat)
```

[image: second plot]

Another approach is to save your call to `ggplot` as an expression, which is unevaluated.  Then you just evaluate it whenever you want.  It is almost like typing the code each time (it is different in some ways but that is the best analogy I can think of).

```
## not wild about this one
myplotcall <- expression(ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_point())

## look at it (literally just the input)
myplotcall
expression(ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point())

## use it
eval(myplotcall)
```

[image: third plot]

```
## change it
dat <- data.frame(x = 21:30, y = runif(10))
eval(myplotcall)
```

[image: fourth plot]

You can change the data in the `ggplot` object itself.  I think that this approach would be the most prone to problems as you are mucking with internals of an object that was not really intended to be changed by the user (i.e., just because we can does not mean we should).  This is more appropriately done with the `%+%` operator (see joran's answer)

```
## not wild about this either
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
g ## use it
```

[image: fifth plot]

```
## change it
dat <- data.frame(x = 31:40, y = runif(10))
g$data <- dat
g
```

[image: sixth plot]