# Replace dataset(s) of an existing ggplot having multiple datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

The main goal is to finely control y-scales of a facetted ggplot per facet row. My strategy is to build a separate plot for each row and binding them together.

I'd like to start with an existing ggplot object. To build a plot for each facet row, I plan on subsetting the original data and replace the dataset using the operator `%+%`.
However this seems not possible when there are multiple datasets over different layers.

**Is there a possibility to replace *multiple/all* the datasets in a ggplot using `%+%`?**

MWE below: This approach works for plot `ga` in which the second dataset `dat2a` doesn't contain the facetting variable. However it does not work with the second example `gb`.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat1 <- data.frame(x=runif(9),y=runif(9), b=rep(1:3,3)  )
dat2a <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),c=c(1,1))
dat2b <- data.frame(a=c(0.5,1,2),c=c(0.5,1,1),b=c(1,2,3))

ga   <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(b~.) +
    geom_point(data=dat2a, aes(x=a, y=c), color='red')
gb   <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(b~.) +
    geom_point(data=dat2b, aes(x=a, y=c), color='red')

# example a) working
    ga
    #Replot ga using the altered data frame
    ga %+% dat1[dat1$b==2,]
# example b) not working
    gb
    #Replot g using the altered data frame
    gb %+% dat1[dat1$b==2,]
```

Comment: What is `dat`? Are you sure you are meant to be calling `dat` in the square brackets and not `dat1` eg. `gb %+% dat1[dat1$b==2,]`.

Comment: Indeed `dat` should be `dat1`, well spotted. I edited the code with the correction. (Also added the library ggplot2). Now the example should be running.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Below workaround achieves the desired result. However, it also modifies the data of the original ggplot object. Somehow the copied ggplot object remains linked to the original. While the workaround answers the question it does not solve the problem.

---

Using `str` on the ggplot object gave me some hints. Each layer can be accessed with `gb$layers` and each layer has an element `$data`. This allows to find out which layer has its own data.frame:

`lapply(gb_new2$layers, function(layer) is.data.frame(layer$data))`

It turns out that replacing these data.frames will achieve the desired result.

*(Though I'm not sure if there are unwanted consequences from this replacement, such as wrong axis scaling. Or can somebody confirm that such calculations are only performed in a later step when calling `ggplot_build()`? I.e. are we still dealing with an object `gb` that is very much the same as the initial plot definition?)*

The following lines provide the required alteration of the `ggplot` object `gb`.

```
gb_new <- gb
dat2b_extracted <- gb_new$layers[[2]]$data
gb_new$layers[[2]]$data <- dat2b_extracted[dat2b_extracted$b==2,]

gb_new %+% dat1[dat1$b==2,]
```

This can be automatized using below. Though I have to admit it still feels very hacky.

```
# copy ggplot object
gb_new2 <- gb

# edit copy of ggplot
for (it in seq_along(gb_new2$layers)){
    # get data.frame of layer
        temp_df <- gb_new2$layers[[it]]$data
    # subset and replace it
        if(is.data.frame(temp_df)) { gb_new2$layers[[it]]$data <- temp_df[temp_df$b==2,] }
}
# plot
gb_new2 %+% dat1[dat1$b==2,]
```

Comment: I have just noticed that this results in some errors for my intended use case. It seems that copying a ggplot object does not copy the underlying data. Then altering the data of the ggplot object `gb_new2`also alters the data of the original `gb`. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431861/ggplot2-create-an-independent-copy-from-an-ggplot-object